# How do I repair supposedly corrupted MS Works Word files?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a lot of old .wps files which I'd like to open.

Word 2007 reports that some are corrupt but doesn't attempt to recover them.

I know some have some defunct Greek polytonic fonts and maybe that is a problem..

any ideas how I might recover/open these files?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Other than using Word 2007, what else have you tried? Have you tried to convert them first?

Answer (score 0):

At [support.microsoft.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328085008/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315757), I read that "the Works document file may be from an older version. 
In this case, download the Works 4 Converter and try to open the document". 
There is a Wayback Machine copy of the download page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160508124931/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7264),
but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

You can see a third-party copy of the "How to" document [here](https://alawayem.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-open-works-60-works-70-works-80.html). 
I got some sort of content warning the first time I went there,
but I don't see why. 
The center of that document
appears to be identical to the Microsoft document. 
There are some links on the right side that may be politically provocative,
but are safe for work.